# How to remove a particular character from a txt file?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Have a txt with contents :

```
 {
 hello : 1,two:three,four:five,six:seven,
 }
```

how to remove the last  `,`  in the above string ?

while using them as dictionaries for further. it cant be parsed because of the last delimiter.

code :

```
import json
d2=json.load(open(test.txt))
```

i cant change the source code. coz i am extracting data from a json file(json.dump) and creating a new json. is there any way of doing that other than dump/changing the source code

Comment: What are you planning to do with the content once you remove the last `,`

Comment: i am running a loop and i dont need the last ,    need to remove that for further parsing

Comment: Can you add that code as well where you are parsing these strings

Comment: What format is the txt file, custom? Are you parsing JSON with regex?

Comment: building a random JSON data in a particular format in bulk using faker lib. so needed to remove the last ,

Comment: I think it's better if you fix the problem at source, since what you have is not a valid json string, so fix your source to generate correct json strings

Comment: Just a heads up - it will also fail because the property names are not quoted.

Comment: I think this problem should be solved at the source. How are you creating that file? If you properly do it, no need to go through all this.

Comment: If you have any control of the code that produces the files - you should fix it to produce valid JSONs

Comment: just changing it to `{
 "hello" : 1,"two":"three","four":"five","six":"seven"
 }
` will solve your problem

Comment: if i try parsing file/removing the last delimiter (,) with regex it would a cause prblm ? need suggestions.

Comment: Your problem is in generating the JSON. Put your data in correct structure (dict or list) and use `json.dump()`

Comment: i cant change the source code. coz i am extracting data from a json file(json.dump) and creating a new json. is there any way of doing that other than dump/changing the source code

Comment: Well whatever regex you can come up with will be complex, and can break if not thoroughly tested

Comment: oh.. ok vl give it a try.

Comment: every time i generate it . the delimited would be second from last in the json. may be if ican find a way to remove the last second character in the file. It might work . any suggestions ? @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: You can use an alternative json parser such as https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson/ that can parse invalid `json` (check out the `allow_trailing_comma` option)

Comment: That would be another question, where you show us the code which generates these json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode an invalid json string in python](/questions/12511159/how-to-decode-an-invalid-json-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This removes the last `,` in your string without the need of any further `import`'s.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
   s = f.read()
s = s[::-1].replace(',', '', 1)[::-1]
```

the output of `s` is then:

```
{
 hello : 1,two:three,four:five,six:seven
}
```

Comment: So you are reversing the string twice, just to replace the last comma?

Comment: In fact, yes, but this just changes the representation of the string

Comment: But that's extra computation, and really inefficient for longer strings Also this gives you a string, but you cannot use it to create a dictionary

Comment: This way is the fastest way possible to reverse strings because you just change the representation (see [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27843760/8597864) or [second](https://www.journaldev.com/23647/python-reverse-string))

Comment: It still is `O(n)` where n is the length of the list, not sure what you mean by fastest here

Answer (score 1):

Simple `replace` should work fine.

```
broken_json = '''{
  hello : 1,two:three,four:five,six:seven,
  bye : 42,ick:poo,zoo:bar,}'''
j = broken_json.replace(',}', '}').replace(',\n}','\n}')
```

The result at this point is still not valid JSON, because the dictionary keys need to be quoted; but this is outside the scope of your question so I will not try to tackle that part.

Answer (score -2):

```
string ='{hello : 1,two:three,four:five,six:seven,}'
length = len(string)

for i in range(length):
   if(string[i] == ','):
      string2 = string[0:i] + string[i + 1:length]
print (string2)
```

The output type would be a string. So, convert it to a dict later.

Comment: And what if there are commas in the value or the key e.g `{
 "tw,o":"three","four":"fi,ve"
 }`

Comment: This is horribly inefficient as it reprocesses the whole text file every time it finds a comma. Also it won't work when there are more than one dictionary.

Comment: This only replaces the last comma. Did you run it ? @DeveshKumarSingh . This was just an idea of how it work for the type(text) you had mentioned ,Selcuk. If you want it for more dictionaries.I would suggest you to write a function to loop through all the text.

Comment: Also how do you convert your output to a dict later? Because you won't be able to, give it a try

Comment: @AkalyaRaj It regenerates and overwrites `string2` for every comma.

Comment: I have posted another code for efficiency.In any case,the question only implied one string @Selcuk

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary

Comment: @AkalyaRaj Have you tried converting it yourself? It won't work.

Comment: Yeah,sorry my bad.Just tried.But i tried another way of splitting and creating Dict.It did work.So perhaps there are other ways to do that.

Comment: Your newer answer has issues as well

Answer (score -2):

```
import re
string ='{hello : 1,two:three,four:five,six:seven,}'
match = re.search(r'(.*),[^,]*$', string)
print (match.group(1)+"}")
```

Try this @selcuk for an efficient one

Comment: Perhaps better to update your original answer instead of creating a new one?

Comment: This will delete the last `key: value` pair for valid dictionaries, for example `string ='{hello : 1,two:three,four:five,six:seven}'`

Comment: I am bit new to posting answers ,let me try to do it from next time .Thanks for the tip

Comment: You misunderstood me. Your code deletes the last pair in my example.

Comment: @selcuk,Can i know the example.It still works fine for me :?

Comment: [The comment from 25 minutes ago](/questions/56661270/how-to-remove-a-particular-character-from-a-txt-file/56662142#comment99892291_56661688) has a specific example which produces `{hello : 1,two:three,four:five}` where it should produce `{hello : 1,two:three,four:five,six:seven}` i.e. not remove the last key when there isn't a trailing comma.

Comment: I am sorry I am not able to understand here.That code doesn't remove the last key,pair.It just extracts the characters before last comma and concatenates a bracket at the end. I think we cab leave at this considering there is already a good answer  .Cheers

Comment: Try putting `string ='{hello : 1,two:three,four:five,six:seven}'` in your code and you will see that `match.group(1)+"}"` gives you `{hello : 1,two:three,four:five}`